# block duplicate records while insert

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

The Below is My Insert Query, The Duplication is not happened in all that had been inserted but it occurred in some cases and I can't able to find the find the Error  and I had been stuck in this for one week ,Please help me

```
INSERT INTO Lgen_KYCApprvlDoc
(
  Cust_FK,CustCode,PrpslNo,Doc_FK,
  RecdDt,RecdBy,DocRefNo,DocRefDt,DocValue,
  DocVldUpto,Remarks,DocStage,DocStat,SentFlag,
  KYCID,CrtdDt,CrtdBy,LstModDt,LstModBy,ApprvdDt,
  ApprvdBy,Mandatory,Validity,DocVerifiedStatus
)
select hdnCustomerId,txtCustId,NULL,Pk,
Nullif(b.ReceivedDate,'') As ReceivedDate,
b.ReceivedBy,b.DocRefNo,
Nullif(b.DocIssuedDate,'') As DocIssuedDate,b.DocValue,
Nullif(B.ValidUpto,'') As
ValidUpto,
b.Remarks,b.strdocstage,b.strdocStatus,NULL,b.hdnCboType,
b.SysDate,b.Userid,b.SysDate,b.Userid,
NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
From #Lgen_KYCTable b 
Left Outer Join Lgen_KYCApprvlDoc A With(Nolock) 
On a.CustCode=B.txtCustid and A.Doc_FK=b.PK
Where B.Strdocstatus='R' and A.PK_Id Is Null
```

Comment: show us your the table structure or mention your primary key or Identity column...

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Some product specific code there...)

Comment: Identity Seed Increment Not For Replication
PK_Id 1                1               0                          Pk_id is My Identity Column and The Duplication not occurred in Pk_id but all other data are getting Duplicated  and I am using SQL Server 2010

Comment: Cust_FK and Doc_FK are Foreign Keys

Answer (score 1):

To guarantee uniqueness in a table, you'd make sure to have a unique constraint on the table.

Here is an example table:

```
items (gtin, description, price, ...)
```

Here the GTIN (Global Trade Item Number) would be the natural unique key for the table. You make it the primary key, which guarantees an item to be unique in the table.

Some people prefer to work with technical IDs instead. So the table would look like this:

```
items (item_id, gtin, description, price, ...)
```

Here `item_id` would possibly be the primary key and thus be unique. But you would also add a unique constraint on the GTIN, so as to ensure to have no duplicate items in the table. (You could also do it vice versa and make the GTIN the primary key and add a unique constraint to the `item_id`.)

This can also be multiple columns, e.g. people having several phone numbers:

```
person_phone (person_phone_id, person_id, phone_number, phone_type)
```

Again `person_phone_id` would be a technical ID you want to introduce or not, but in any case you want a unique constraint on `person_id` + `phone_number`, so as not to have two entries for the same person and phone number.

So all you have to do is find the columns that must be unique in your table and add that constraint. E.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE Lgen_KYCApprvlDoc ADD CONSTRAINT unique_apprvldoc UNIQUE (Cust_FK, Doc_FK);
```

Comment: I have one more Column in that table Name is validity , and I should Allow to insert when the value of validity is 'E' can it possible after I use the Constraint that you have mentioned above?

Comment: You are saying that you want uniqueness in your table except for records with `validity = 'E'`? Records with `validity = 'E'` are allowed to be dupliactes? Yes?

Comment: Yes I want uniqueness in the table except for records with validity = 'E'

Comment: Then you must use a trick. A NULL is an unknown value, so are two nulls treated equal or not equal? The values are unknown so they *could* be equal or *could* be different. A *unique constraint* treats them as *different* by mere *definition*. So add a computet column to your table with null for validity = 'E' and a fixed value otherwise. Then add this column to your index. Thus you can have as many duplicates for validity = 'E' as you want - they are all treated as different - whereas validity ≠ NULL will be checked for uniqueness (i.e. the other columns in the index must be unique).